# What does the => operator in the for-each loop mean?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I understand that `=>` operator in *PHP* is used to assign values in an associative array:

```
$array = array(key1 => value1, key2 => value2, key3=> value3);
```

I understand that `for-each loop` in PHP is iterated like

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

But I have encountered something like

```
foreach ($question->get_order($qa) as $value => $ansid) {...}
```

**I do not understand the `$value => $ansid` part of it.**

`$question -> get_order($qa)` returns an array. We want to iterate through it, so it should be `foreach ($question -> get_order($qa) as $value) {...}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=>` operator assigns the keys of the array to the variable on the left hand side, and the value to the variable on the right hand side. For example, if you array is

`$array = array(key1 => value1, key2 => value2, key3=> value3);`

then

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

will print

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

It is particularly useful if your array keys also have a meaning and you need them inside the `for`-loop, separate from the values.

For example:

```
$students_by_id = array( 1234 => "John Smith", 2372 => "Pete Johnson" );
$grades = array( 1234 => 87, 2372 => 68 );

foreach( $grades as $student_id => $grade ) {
  echo $students_by_id[$student_id] . " scored " . $grade . " / 100 points.\n";
}
```

Note that if the array is "not associative", e.g.

```
$array = array( value1, value2, value3 );
```

then PHP will create numeric indexes for you, and the `$key` variable in

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value )
```

will run through 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., making your loop effectively equivalent to

```
for ($key = 0, $key < count($array); ++$key) {
  $value = $array[$key];
  // ...
}
```

In general I would still recommend the `=>` notation, if not for efficiency then at least in case indices go missing from the list or you decide to switch to an associative array after all.

Answer (score 4):

In a for loop, you can use the same operator to get the keys as well as the values. The variable before `=>` will get the key of each item, and the variable behind it will get its value.

So in your specific case, `$value` will get the key of the item (`'key1'` on the first iteration) and `$ansid` will get the value (`'value1'` on the first iteration).

This feature is particularly useful for arrays with (named) keys, but it will also work for normal arrays, in which case you get the numeric indices for the keys.

Answer (score 2):

The $value => $ansid will return the key and the value, not just the value.

So if its a plain array, key would likely be 0,1,2,3,4 etc and value would be v0,v1,v2,v3,v4.

Comment: This could be improved if you used their sample array.

Comment: `$question = get_order($qa)` returns an indexed array, not an associative array. So should I learn (from your answer) that `$value` will get the indices that is 0,1,2,3... and `$ansid` will get the actual contents of the array?

Comment: Yes, if the array is indexed, then the indices are automatically numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 
It is similar as if you would have written `array( 0 => first, 1 => second, ...)` yourself, rather than `array( first, second, ...)`.

Comment: Yes your question gets slight originality points, because as we see it will automatically index the key as the array index for plain arrays in PHP.